# Web Api Post method is receiving NULL parameter always

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, json.net

I am trying to pass List as a parameter to web Api , Using below code;

**Client Side**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult>BatchUpdatePartial(MVCxGridViewBatchUpdateValues<NewWorkItem, int> batchValues)
    {

        var updatedItems = new List<NewWorkItem>();

        string url = "http://localhost:9198/api/values";

        foreach (var item in batchValues.Update)
        {
            if (batchValues.IsValid((item)))
            {
                var updatedVals = new NewWorkItem();

                updatedVals.CPK_ID = item.CPK_ID;
                updatedVals.BYR_ID = item.BYR_ID;
                updatedVals.P_ID = item.P_ID;
                updatedVals.CPK_PRI_FLG = item.CPK_PRI_FLG;
                updatedItems.Add(updatedVals);
            }

            else
                batchValues.SetErrorText(item, "Correct Vallidation Errors");
        }

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedItems);
            string response = client.UploadString(url, serialisedData);
            Object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
         }

        return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", NewWorkItem.GridData);
    }
```

**Server Side**

```
  public string Post([FromBody]string[] values)
        {
        string seperator = ",";
        string data = string.Join(seperator, values.ToList<string>());
        string result = string.Format("Succesfully uploaded: {0}", data);
        return result;
        }
```

But I am always getting NULL inside the values at server side ?

Can you please suggest me solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Both methods you have shown are server side code. Which method is not working and what is your client side code

Comment: This sounds like a fairly simple issue to use breakpoints on and step through. If you haven't used them before, breakpoints are a lifesaver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: The 'client' here is some sort of analysis engine or task manager, but it is pretty clear through the titles what is consuming what.  The issue is that he is sending a list of objects and the server is expecting an array of strings.  He's using Json.Net to serialize it, and the semantics of Json.Net mean that there's no way this is serializing in a way the server is going to interpret as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not actually sending a `string[]` the way your POST method expects.  You are sending `serializedData`, which is, by your own definition, a serialization of `updatedItems`.  `updatedItems` is a list of a reference type - you do not provide the definition of it here, but I guarantee you it is not going to serialize the same way a string does.

You will need to change `updatedItems` to be `List<string>` or something similar.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply it did work, I used below code;                           
                var strings = (from o in updatedItems
                               select o.ToString()).ToList();
                string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strings);
                string response = client.UploadString(url, serialisedData);              But At the Web Api side do i need to reconvert it to Object ? If so how should I do that ? As I need my model to update the database through Web Api

Comment: @Rupali If you need the actual model, then you shouldn't be taking in `string[]`, but the `List<NewWorkItem>` instead.  In which case, your original serialize and invoke option should work.  However, the semantics of deserialization in WCF can be a little opaque, so if you run into problems with a `List<NewWorkItem>` input, I would probably just make the signature `string serializedWorkItems`, pass in the json serialization from your client, and then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewWorkItem>>(serializedWorkItems)` to get the strongly typed objects you need.

Comment: @Rupali Also, if this ended up working for you, please be sure to accept the answer.